# update the uploaded file yii2

Tags: yii, controller, upload, yii2

I have used following to upload image and save it in server and database. Now I want to write a controller to update the uploaded image. how to do it???

controller

```
public function actionInvitfile()
{
    $model = new Applicants();
    $imgName = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;

        if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
        $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
        $model->file->saveAs('uploads/invitfile/' . $imgName . '.' . $model->file->extension);
        $model->invitations_file='uploads/invitfile/'. $imgName . '.' . $model->file->extension;
        $model->save(false);
        }
   return $this->goHome();
}
```

Model

```
    class Applicants extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $file;
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'applicants';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['file'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'pdf'],
        ];
    }
```

Please, Help me!)

Comment: Create update action where you pass ID of that object, load it from database and update record. Btw. using `save(false)` is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can work

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
         $imgName = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
         $model = Applicants->findModel($id);
        if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){

         unlink($model->invitations_file); 


         $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
         $model->file->saveAs('uploads/invitfile/' . $imgName . '.' . $model->file->extension);
         $model->invitations_file='uploads/invitfile/'. $imgName . '.' . $model->file->extension;
         $model->save(false);
        }
   return $this->goHome();

    }
```

but here you have official documentation of the kartij blog where you can learn much more and have a better answer to your problem:
http://webtips.krajee.com/advanced-upload-using-yii2-fileinput-widget/

Comment: `$model = Applicants->findModel($id);` ? seriously **(ಠ‿ಠ)**

Comment: you know a best way  for make this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update a single image, then in update function, before loading post variables, just keep the old image in a variable. The following code will help you:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $oldImage = $model->banner;

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        //get picture data and save it
        $imageFile = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'banner');
        if($imageFile) {
            unlink(Yii::getAlias('@app').'/../../uploads/banners/' . $oldImage);

            $fileName = $imageFile->baseName.'_'.time().'.'.$imageFile->extension;
            $imageFile->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@app').'/../../uploads/banners/' . $fileName);

            $model->banner = $fileName;
            $model->save();
        } else {
            $model->banner = $oldImage;
            $model->save(false);

        }

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```